# Why won't this configuration of fins work?

Tags: construction, model-rocketry

So I was building a rocket. I tried to find a more efficient way of attaching the fins.

So then I realized how easy it would be if I just attached them like this:
[image: Possible fin configuration.]

So instead of  having the fins perpendicular to the body, what if we had fins parallel to the body?

Why would this be a bad idea?

What about 4 fins?

[image: Possible fin configuration.]

And I could not resist but ask if this will actually affect anything:

[image: Possible fin configuration]

Comment: I'm no rocket scientist, but I would think the air getting trapped in the pinch points would lead to some really nasty vortices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of the fins is to keep the rocket on course. When your rocket goes off course, the rocket body is off-axis relative to the rocket's velocity vector. This means the side of two fins is exposed to the wind streaming down the rocket body. This creates a force that pushes the rocket back on course.

In your configuration, when there's a force on the fins, the fins exert a torque on the rocket, making it spin. Sometimes you want that (spin adds stability), but generally you want constant spin, not a spin rate that depends on how much your rocket goes off-axis.

In addition, the fins have to be much larger to have the same effective area: some of the fin area is in front of the rocket body, meaning any force acting on this area would have acted on the body anyway.

Comment: Don't you think that the poster is just trying to make a bad joke with his Hakenkreuz swastika?

Comment: The possibility of a troll occurred to me, but on the off-chance he's serious...

Comment: It might be the future of spaceflight ;-) "They" started it, you know, with suborbital flights Calais-London. But even then and there rocket fin shape wasn't political enough to compromise von Braun's design. It didn't even leave any mark on his Saturn füh.. füh.. füh.. five. When you "land" with a supersonic V2, your target cannot hear you scream.

Comment: @LocalFluff That was the intent. But now I wonder, is there some weird design like that that can resist the spin?

Answer (score 4):

We don't know if it might work or not, it entirely depends on what effect are you after. But such a fin configuration will cause spin along the long axis (might be desirable for all we know, smaller launch vehicles are often intentionally spun for flight stability), and pressure on the fins from both sides and lateral to them won't be equal in magnitude, which might cause vibration, destabilize the vehicle and snap the fins right off.

Both effects are due to pressure of compressed air as the vehicle gains speed and ascends through the denser part of the atmosphere not being equal at both sides of each fin:

[image]

Comment: Big problem here:  He's talking model rocketry--he has no way to de-spin the craft later in flight.  What's going to happen when the chute comes out??

Comment: @LorenPechtel Hey, I'm not saying this is a good idea.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - It would depend on spin at apogee, I would think. Most model rocket engines (At least the F level and below) have a short delay period built in for the rocket to lose thrust before the chute/streamers deploy. If the loss of thrust = loss of spin, not much effect. Also, depending on how the recovery system is packed, the elastic band that connects would spin and twist with no effect on chute.